# Save index of array after terminating app

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UILabel that will display a quote from my Quotes array. I have a function set up that moves to the next element in an array every time a button is pressed. This button will only be activated once every 24 hours so users will likely close the app until they can press the button again and get a new quote. How can I save the position of my Quotes array so it doesn't start all over from the beginning each time?

Should this be done in the AppDelegate applicationWillTerminate or save it using Core Data?

```
 let quotes = ["quote1", "quote2", "quote3", "quote4"]

   @objc func getNewQuote(){


        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        let currentIndex = quotes.index(of: quotesLabel.text ?? String()) ?? -1
        var nextIndex = currentIndex+1
        defaults.set(nextIndex, forKey: "savedIndexKey")
        nextIndex = quotes.indices.contains(nextIndex) ? nextIndex : 0
        quotesLabel.text = quotes[nextIndex]

        let savedInteger = defaults.integer(forKey: "savedIndexKey")
        print(savedInteger)
    }

  let gridButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.titleLabel?.text = "Button "
    button.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getNewQuote), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that small a value, you can use UserDefaults.

Save your Integer index to User Defaults by something like

```
let indexKey = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "savedIndexKey")
```

and you can update the value of the index by

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(index, forKey: "savedIndexKey")
```

You can read more about the UserDefaults [Apple User Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

Comment: would it be best to add this inside my getNewQuote function?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You should save the index each time you increment it. So that even if you app crashes, or something else goes wrong, index would have always been saved.

Comment: I am having trouble replacing the new savedInteger with the initial currentIndex, can you help me with that.

Comment: What's the issue that you get?

Comment: if its the users first time then the savedInteger from User Defaults is empty and can only be set from the initial function, how can I update the currentIndex value to the savedIndex value?

Comment: @soRazor If it's the first time, then the `integer(forKey:` should return 0, which should be ok, since arrays start from zero, and you have to use the same index for array of quotes, right? If however you want it to start from a particular index, you can perhaps save another `bool` in `UserDefaults` for whether it's the first time the user has opened the app.

Comment: should let currentIndex = quotes.index(of: quotesLabel.text ?? String()) ?? -1 be replaced by default.integer(forKey: "savedIndex") ? i tried that but it isn't working properly

Comment: In your `getNewQuote` function, just get the saved index first, (which for the first time would be 0), increment it, save the incremented value, and then fetch the quote for that index and set it to label. In your function where you set up the label, (probably your `viewdidLoad`) just get the current index, get the quote for that index, and set it to label (don't increment it)

Comment: Your code is wired up too weirdly right now. You don't need to look for the quote index by finding the string location in array, when you can just get the index from UserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is mostly used for a large amount of objects, user defaults for simple settings and keychain for sensitive info (such as an app password).

You can use user defaults in `applicationWillTerminate`.